# how to Create Get Products Api based on Category Id using limit & offset though GET Method & display the api response in json?

Tags: opencart

```
<?php
class ControllerSystemProducts1 extends Controller{

private $debugIT=false;

public function getProducts(){
$results = array();


    $query  = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT *, pd.name AS name, p.image, m.name AS manufacturer, (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount pd2 WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id AND pd2.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_customer_group_id') . "' AND pd2.quantity = '1' AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS discount, (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_customer_group_id') . "' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special, (SELECT points FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_reward pr WHERE pr.product_id = p.product_id AND customer_group_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_customer_group_id') . "') AS reward, (SELECT ss.name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "stock_status ss WHERE ss.stock_status_id = p.stock_status_id AND ss.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS stock_status, (SELECT wcd.unit FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "weight_class_description wcd WHERE p.weight_class_id = wcd.weight_class_id AND wcd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS weight_class, (SELECT lcd.unit FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "length_class_description lcd WHERE p.length_class_id = lcd.length_class_id AND lcd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS length_class, (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r1 WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id AND r1.status = '1' GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r2 WHERE r2.product_id = p.product_id AND r2.status = '1' GROUP BY r2.product_id) AS reviews, p.sort_order FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer m ON (p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id) WHERE p.product_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') ."'");






    $results=$query->rows;
        if(count($results )){
            $json['success']    = true;
            $json['product_description']= $results ;
        }else {
            $json['success']    = false;
        }

        if ($this->debugIt) {
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($json);
            echo '</pre>';

        } else {
            $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
        }

}
```

in this code i am trying to get the product description through get method its working fine but along with this i need obtaine the product based on the category id using limit and offset .how can i do this?

Comment: What version of OpenCart are you using?

Comment: v.2.3.0.2 opencart version which i have installed

Comment: do help me out solve this

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Shri.  It's better to post information that can help people who are trying to help you.  You said Abdullah's answer gave you an error but you didn't say what.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code this way. Hope it may be helpful for you

```
public function getProducts($data){

$results = [];

 $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT *, pd.name AS name, p.image, m.name AS manufacturer, (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount pd2 WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id AND pd2.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_customer_group_id') . "' AND pd2.quantity = '1' AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS discount, (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_customer_group_id') . "' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special, (SELECT points FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_reward pr WHERE pr.product_id = p.product_id AND customer_group_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_customer_group_id') . "') AS reward, (SELECT ss.name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "stock_status ss WHERE ss.stock_status_id = p.stock_status_id AND ss.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS stock_status, (SELECT wcd.unit FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "weight_class_description wcd WHERE p.weight_class_id = wcd.weight_class_id AND wcd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS weight_class, (SELECT lcd.unit FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "length_class_description lcd WHERE p.length_class_id = lcd.length_class_id AND lcd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS length_class, (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r1 WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id AND r1.status = '1' GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r2 WHERE r2.product_id = p.product_id AND r2.status = '1' GROUP BY r2.product_id) AS reviews, p.sort_order FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer m ON (p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category pc ON (p.product_id = pc.product_id) p.product_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') ."'";

    if($data['category_id']){
         $sql .= " AND pc.category_id =". (int)$data['category_id'];
    }

    if($data['limit']){
         $sql .= " Limit ". $data['limit'];
    }

    if($data['offset']){
         $sql .= " OFFSET ". $data['offset']
    }

    $query  = $this->db->query($sql)    
    ....
    ....

}
```